# NEED HELP!!!! 3 boxes text above image below image aligned to bottom

Tags: html, css

[screenshot of what i need help with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BF7O.png)

i would like the phone images to be aligned to bottom so that they are all evenly aligned horizontally. been trying everything but cant get it to work. i promise i searched alot. maybe my search terms or description wasn't right but i couldn't find a solution. i appreciate any help.

timber framework

```
 div class="wrapper">
<div class="row content-grid-3">

    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="feature-column medium left">
            <span class="feature-icon large icon-reelwards color-blue-light"></span>
                <div class="feature-text">
                    <h5>Reelwards</h5>
                        <p>In case it’s not enough connecting with your fellow anglers and getting all the tips you could want for free, NetFish also offers you Reelwards for using our app and building your social fishing network. Earn points in a number of ways, then trade them in for a variety of equipment and other fun items.</p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="feature-column medium center">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0240/7519/files/screen-reelwards_0b97aca8-818b-4ed4-94bf-0e84ddd52894.png?4986474463632102874" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">


        <div  class="feature-column medium left ">
            <span class="feature-icon large icon-images color-blue-light"></span>
                <div class="feature-text">
                    <h5>Share Photos</h5>
                        <p>With an easy to see layout and plenty of detail if you want to share, the Catch Feed details allows other users to see what you used to catch that monster...or minnow. Get ‘Likes’ and comments, start a conversation centered around your favorite catch!</p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="feature-column medium center">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0240/7519/files/screen-catch_photo_d9c20c6c-1f48-47e8-aedb-67d834aab403.png?4986474463632102874" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">

        <div  class="feature-column medium left">
            <span class="feature-icon large icon-recipes color-blue-light"></span>
                <div class="feature-text">
                    <h5>Recipes</h5>
                        <p>While we encourage catch-and-release fishing as much as possible, sometimes you’ll end up wanted to eat that beautiful fish you caught. Simply go to the Recipes section and look up the type of fish you caught to see our suggestions. Along with the recipe, you’ll also find beer and wine suggestions.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-column medium center">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0240/7519/files/screen-recipe_8cf081cd-1938-4d52-9a26-90d65674e4d7.png?4986474463632102874" />
        </div>


    </div>
 </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Where's your code? We need a [mcve] to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide any code, so I'll tell you one way of many how to do it. Add to your parent 2 fields: `display: flex` and`flex-direction: column` and to your content(description) add `flex: 1`. Flex: 1 will stretch you description to as max as possible.

[image: flex image]